# Ensuring globally hyperbolic geodesically-complete spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, causality, geodesics

Let's say we have an incomplete spacetime A that is globally hyperbolic, does there necessary exist a globally hyperbolic completion?

My guess is no, in which case what further restrictions can be placed on A to ensure that it can always be extended to geodesically-complete globally hyperbolic spacetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider Kruskal manifold (omitting the future and past singularities at $r=0$). It is a globally hyperbolic spacetime as well known and it is a maximally extended manifold. However there are incomplete causal geodesics: These reaching the singularities. It is impossible to complete them. So the answer to your first question is: NO.

Comment: Are there non-globally hyperbolic, geodesically-complete extensions of the Kruskal manifold?

Comment: No, it does not admit any extension.